# How do I programatically capture the output of a command on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, prompt, text-files

What the question says.

Ultimately what I want is to execute gcc and [capture the output if there's an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460111/trying-compile-a-c-code-with-php/). The problem is errors are written to stderr instead of stdout. On Linux I can do

```
gcc foo.c 2>&1
```

How can I accomplish this on Windows?

Comment: Actually, the question says almost nothing. What is "the Windows prompt?"

Comment: You want something like a text screenshot of whatever is showing in a command prompt?

Comment: Re-wrote the question for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is. Simply right click into the console window, select `Mark`. With your mouse select the desired area and right click. Now you can paste it into a text file with Ctrl-V.

If you need the output of a program into a text file, run it like this:

`myprogram.exe > myfile.txt`

See here about redirecting:
1. [Using command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)
2. [Redirecting Error Messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930)

You can do what you want like this: `D:\>dir 1> test.txt 2> testerr.txt`

Comment: I tried that. But, at the command prompt, the output to appear ... But the output is not displayed when pointing to a text file.

Comment: your program/script will have to get that info from the text file. There is a util somewhere called 'tee' that redirects stdout to a file while still showing it on the console.

Comment: Yeah, is it. Thanks... 
How its works? Why i can't get the output just with:
`gcc > myfile.txt`
Why i need to put 2, this way? gcc 2> myfile.txt

Comment: @Richard: `>` redirection is the same as `1>` (which is `stdout` redirection). `2>` redirection is `stderr` redirection. All-in-all, this is exactly the same as in Linux.

Comment: @all: I'm puzzled this answer got so many upvotes. The correct and short answer to question `How do I do the same in Windows?` should have been: `You do it the same way as in Linux.`

Answer (score 4):

Richard, your "accepted answer" is too long and it is too wrong.

The short answer to your question (as currently stated in your last sentence: *"How can I accomplish this on Windows?"*) is:

### Exactly like you do it on Linux!

---

But I'll ***also*** give you a long answer.

Your `2>&1` redirection works in a `cmd.exe` window the same way. I even re-tested it right now, since my cmd.exe experience is a bit rusty. I used this Ghostscript command (intentionally meant to produce output on stdout as well as on stderr):

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=nullpage -dFirstPage=12 -dLastPage=11 my-20-page-test.pdf
```

I got all the expected output into the shell window. Then I did:

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=nullpage -dFirstPage=12 -dLastPage=11 my-20-page-test.pdf ^
          1>stdout.log
```

and stderr still printed into the window, but stdout.log had the 'missing' original output. Next I did:

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=nullpage -dFirstPage=12 -dLastPage=11 my-20-page-test.pdf ^
          2>stderr.log
```

and stdout now printed into window, while stderr.log had the rest of Ghostscript's messages. Next:

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=nullpage -dFirstPage=12 -dLastPage=11 my-20-page-test.pdf ^
          1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

and (as expected): no output in window, all output divided up between stdout.log and stderr.log. Last test:

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=nullpage -dFirstPage=12 -dLastPage=11 my-20-page-test.pdf ^
          1>all.log 2>&1
```

and result now:

1. nothing in window,
2. everything in all.log.

***Which is the same behaviour as stderr/stdout redirection as on Linux.***

Comment: To be fair, the question looks like that because I edited it. On the other hand, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3460370/revisions) is what it looked like before I did it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output of a particular *command*, there's a simple way to push console output to a file.

Here's a trivial example using the 'dir' command (the leading > represents your prompt):

`>dir > diroutput.txt`